# Selenium Htmlunit driver

Tags: java, selenium

I have a problem about selenium. I use Htmlunit driver. driver.switchTo() not working. My code:

```
        String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        output : A
        for (String handle2 : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!oldTab.equalsIgnoreCase(handle2)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(handle2);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        output : A
```

I have a new tab opened but driver object cannot switch to new tab.

`driver.switchTo().window(handle2);`

this code not working.

Comment: better print windowHandle to the console

Comment: Does it ever hit the `driver.switchTo().window(handle2)` line if you run it in a debugger?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it silently fail to do anything, does it do something unexpected, or is there an error message?

Comment: it doesn't give an error message. For example:  I want to do this:  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");  this element is into the new tab  . Than throw expection as 'No such element'. This is mean cannot handle new tab.